# Difference between nothing and system.DBNull

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapp

I am working in VB.NET and I am wondering about the difference between `Nothing` and `System.DBNull`.

When I fire save query at that time I am giving value from grid at runtime like as follow:

```
gvMain.Rows(j).Cells("Brand").Value.ToString()
```

But it shows me error when it has value of `Nothing` and it works perfectlly when it has value of `System.DBnull`.

What to do in this case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164697/net-dbnull-vs-nothing-across-all-variable-types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyword `Nothing` is used to specify or asign that a var of reference type is not pointing anything, no object is instanciated for this var.

`DBNull.Value`, on the other hand, is an object used to point out that a type of a field of the DataBase is of null value.

Answer (score 4):

`Nothing` is of Type `System.Object.`

It represents the default value of any data type.

`DBNull.Value` is of Type `System.DBNull`

If something shows up as `System.DBNull`, that means that even though it doesn't have a value, it has a valid pointer. As you may have found out, it cannot be converted to a string, integer, etc. You must do a check (preferably using `IsDBNull`.

```
If IsDBNull(gvMain.Rows(j).Cells("Brand").Value) Then
    Return String.Empty
Else
    Return gvMain.Rows(j).Cells("Brand").Value.ToString().Trim()
End If
```

Comment: Your example should use `If` instead of `IIf` to be current. `IIf` is not short-circuiting.

Comment: I meant use a [ternary `If`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).