# How to show the text "All" if CUSNO Parameter is selected "NULL" ? Else Show CUSNO.Value in textbox in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I want to show the text "All" in textbox IIF Parameter CUSNO is selected null in SSRS. Else textbox has the Parameter!CUSNO.Value in it.Here's what I've already tried:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!CUSNO.Value), "All", Parameters!CUSNO.Value)
```

Comment: Are you talking about VBA or VB.Net?

Comment: Thats VB.NET...

Comment: Is the parameter multi-value?

Comment: No. It's not multi-value

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your expression, in fact I just created a quick report and test. It worked fine. Do you see the `NULL` checkbox next to the parameter field? Show some screen shots of your parameter setup.

Comment: How are you populating the CUSNO parameter values? Is Allow Blank checked?

Comment: Are you 100% sure IsNothing() is what you want to use?  Is the field actually Null, or is it DBNull?  While for all intents and purposes mean the same thing DBNull != nothing.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600825/difference-between-nothing-and-system-dbnull